# Tabulate based on number of times ID occurs AND another column value R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm formatting a table for a study to count how many times a person had a biological sample collected. The table shows how many separate clinic visits a person had a sample type collected.

I want to count how many times an ID appeared for each sample type. For example, if a person with ID = "1234" had the ID appear 4 times with "DNA" in the SAMPLETYPE column, then they had DNA collected at 4 visits. I want the table to look like this:

| SAMPLETYPE | 1 VISIT | 2 VISITS | 3 VISITS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DNA | 80 | 47 | 24 |
| RNA | 36 | 12 | 6 |
| SERUM | 112 | 89 | 65 |

My dataframe is structured like this:

```
SAMPLETYPE <- c("DNA","DNA","RNA","PLASMA","RNA","RNA","DNA","PLASMA","PLASMA","PLASMA",
"RNA","RNA","RNA")
ID <- c("1","1","1","2","3","2","4","4","4","5","1","1","1")
df <- data.frame(ID,SAMPLETYPE)

df
   ID SAMPLETYPE
1   1        DNA
2   1        DNA
3   1        RNA
4   2     PLASMA
5   3        RNA
6   2        RNA
7   4        DNA
8   4     PLASMA
9   4     PLASMA
10  5     PLASMA
```

Above, ID = 1 had DNA collected at 2 visits and had RNA collected at 1 visit. The expected output would be:

| SAMPLETYPE | 1 VISIT | 2 VISITS | 3 VISITS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DNA | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| RNA | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| PLASMA | 2 | 1 | 0 |

How would I manipulate this dataframe in R to build a table in the format of the example?

Comment: What is the expected output from the tdata given?

Comment: I edited the sample data frame and gave an expected output at the bottom of the question. Is that helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  count(SAMPLETYPE, ID) %>%   # count the combinations
  count(SAMPLETYPE, n) %>%    # count the frequency of combinations
  pivot_wider(names_from = n, names_prefix = "visits_", 
              values_from = nn, values_fill = 0)
```

I get different output from the most recent example data. For example, it looks like ID 1 had 4 RNA visits, and ID 2 & 3 each had 1.

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  SAMPLETYPE visits_1 visits_2 visits_4
  <chr>         <int>    <int>    <int>
1 DNA               1        1        0
2 PLASMA            2        1        0
3 RNA               2        0        1
```

Comment: Apologies, my real table was extremely large, so it looks like my example may have had a typo. This helped -- many thanks!